# Replace a substring using RegEx

Tags: regex

Here is a line in my xyz.csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="SomeDLLNameHere, Version=10.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

All I need to do is replace the 'Version=10.2.6.0' to 'Version=11.0.0.0' .

The program I need to do this in is VSBuild which uses VBScript so I believe.

The problem is that I can't hardcode the 'old' version number. I therefore need to replace the following :

```
<Reference Include="SomeDLLNameHere, Version=10.2.6.0,
```

I therefor need a regex that will match the above bearing in mind that that in the example quoted, the 10.2.6.0 could be anything.

I believe that a regex that would select the text including and between

```
'<Reference Include="SomeDLLNameHere' and '>' is what I need.
```

There are other references to similar requests but none seem top work for me.

I would normally use C# to do this sort of thing and VBScript/Regex is something I avoid like the plague.

Comment: `s/Version=[\d.]+/Version=11.0.0.0/g` will replace every version number to your new one, dunno how you'd do it in VBScript though. Also, if people have helped you you should accept more answers.

Comment: Thanks inTide but there are many dll's referenced and I only need to update one of them, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most regex flavors, you would use this:

```
<Reference Include="SomeDLLNameHere.*?/>
```

For visual studio, I am not sure if the `*?` would work... Try this:

```
\<Reference Include="SomeDLLNameHere[^/]*\/\>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not doing this in code. I need just the bare regex.

Comment: Are you doing it in the find/replace dialog?  That has a very different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern should work

```
"(<Reference[^>]+Version=)([^,]+),"
```

Applied with VBScript

```
  str1 = "<Reference Include=""SomeDLLNameHere, Version=10.2.6.0,"

  ' Create regular expression.
  Set regEx = New RegExp
  regEx.Pattern = "(<Reference[^>]+Version=)([^,]+),"

  ' Make replacement.
  ReplaceText = regEx.Replace(str1, "$111.0.0.0,")
  WScript.echo ReplaceText
```

Gives the correct result

```
<Reference Include="SomeDLLNameHere, Version=11.0.0.0,
```

**UPDATE**

if you need something that matches between `Version=` and the end of the tag use `>` instead of `,`

```
"(<Reference[^>]+Version=)([^>]+)>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex with C# or VBScript is pretty much the same because it all comes to developing the regular expression. Something like this could help:
`<Reference\s+Include\s*=\s*\".+\",\s*Version\s*=\s*.+,`

Not sure what are the rules about case sensitivity and white spaces in csproj files, but this covers the form you described previously. Note that the "+" operator means one or kleen.